# git log between tags using wildcards

Tags: git, jenkins, wildcard, git-diff

Jenkins tags every build with a tag that looks like this:

```
builds/Android_release/1.2-RC1_2016-10-07-16
```

when building a second RC, I would like to get the diff between the two builds. Something like:

```
git shortlog builds/Android_release/1.2-RC1*..builds/Android_release/1.2-RC2*
```

Unfortunately, wildcards do not work in the range.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What if the wildcard matches more than one tag?

Comment: @1615903: good point, I ended up getting the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to do something like this:

```
tag1=$(git tag | grep 1.2-RC1)
tag2=$(git tag | grep 1.2-RC2)
git shortlog $tag1..$tag2
```

Answer (score 0):

- You asked about diff between two tags

```
git diff starting_tag..ending_tag
```

- But I assume that you want commit messages

```
git log --pretty=%B starting_tag..ending_tag
```

- starting tag is pointing to commit that is older then one with ending tag, thus in ascending order - other way around do not work

Comment: I want to use wild cards in the tags, this doesn't fix my problem.